# How to label entities in utterances in IBM Watson Conversation service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In IBM Watson service, I have created my intents and entities, and even defined my dialog with slots. When testing the bot, it performs very poorly in recognizing the entities, especially when there are multiple system entities in an utterance. An example would be:

> Patient was born on 1st of July 1945 and was injured on 2nd June 2017.

How can I manually label entities in test utterances?

Comment: Have you already used the `Improve` menu? There is some help on that https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/logs.html#about-the-improve-component You can work with the existing utterances (logs) and tell WCS how to interpret it.

Comment: The 'improve' function works after the model has been deployed. In this case, it does not help me because I am still in development mode.

Comment: There is no entity updating via Try it Out. If you can expand on what entities you want to get from that sentence though, there may be another solution.